# Deploy Keycloak Docker Image to Azure App Service - cannot create the admin user

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service, keycloak

With Azure App Service it is possible to deploy an application using a container image, as visibile in the image that follows.

[image]

I am deploying the boss/keycloak image from docker hub repository with the configuration visibile here:

[image]

After a successful deployment I am able to access the home page of the application that shows me correctly that I should create an admin user in order to access keycloak.

Now the problem arise. I am not able to access the container using ssh in order to create the admin user through the add-user.sh script.
The azure built-in ssh console from the portal refuses the connection. I also found a guide to create a connection but it fails into an infinte loop and then a timeout. It says that the app is not running, but of course it is, because I can access the home page through http.

A question may be: is there a way to use -e parameters when deploying the container in this way? It that would possibile I could create the user like described in keycloak documentation, but I can't find a way to do it.

I attach some images to explain better what happens.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I guess you tried this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-linux-open-ssh-session

Comment: yes I did with the loop result that you see in the console

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the following variables in the app service Application Settings:

```sh
KEYCLOAK_USER=<USERNAME>
KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=<PASSWORD
```

as documented in https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/

Comment: this was the only way I could do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to execute a command within the container, maybe the following URL could help :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-exec

On the other hand, you could log in using VS code with the azure and docker plugins and ssh into the container that you want to log in.

Comment: unfortunately I am not using Azure Container Instances but Azure Web App and deploying a container instead of the code.
Nevertheless I fixed it changing approach and installing bare-metal keycloak server.

Answer (score 0):

it's easy. Azure only works if the ssh port is 2222.
So you have to use a own Docker Image based on keycloak and modify the port.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).